# Can/do compilers simplify logical expressions involving functions?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization

Some functions which calculate booleans:

```
bool a()
{
   return trueorfalse;
}

bool b()
{
   //...
}

bool c()
{
   //...
}
```

This condition

```
//somewhere else
if((a()&&b()&&c()) || (a()&&b()&&!c()) )
{
    doSomething();
}
```

can also be written as

```
if(a()&&b())
{
   doSomething();
}
```

Will compilers usually optimize this away?

And what about pure boolean values:

```
if((a&&b&&c) || (a&&b&&!c))
{ 
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: It can be written as that *only knowing* that the functions are [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: I don't think so, unless it can _prove_ that c returns the same result every call, and it would probably also have to try to inline c.

Comment: `bool c() { static bool r=true; r = !r; return r;}` for instance.

Comment: If you had used variables instead of function calls then, yes, the compiler will optimize.

Comment: If you **want** it to be optimized this way, why write the overcomplicated condition in the first place?

Comment: In more complicated conditions one might not see such a case as easily. This was more or less a theoretical question by the way. I was just writing an if statement which involved 16 or so statements (a combination of pure boolean variables and functions) and wondered if it was worth it to simplify the expression myself, manually, on the blackboard, or if the compiler will do the work for me anyways.

Comment: I think it is worth trying to simplify it. If it is that complicated, how do you expect the reader of your code (including yourself) to be able to make sense of it later? Perhaps also try to extract the condition into a separate function / functions?

Comment: That condition wasn't actually relevant to anything (it was a quick hack for something I wanted to try out). I just posted that as background to how I came to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the functions may have side effects, the conditional cannot be "optimized" in any way, since all the functions will have to be called (conditionally) in a well-defined manner.

If you do want optimization, you can assign the result to variables first:

```
const bool ba = a(), bb = b(), bc = c();

if (ba && bb && bc || ba && bb && !bc) { /* ... */ } // probably optimized to "ba && bb"
```

It's possible that `constexpr` functions introduced in C++11 will allow for optimization if they yield a constant expression, though, but I'm not sure.

You can even condense this down: In the following code, `f()` has to be called twice:

```
if (f() && false || f() && true)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No they won't.  The reason why is that the optimization would be visible to the user because it would change the observable side effects.  For example In your optimized version `c()` would never execute even though the user explicitly tried to do so.  This **can and will** lead to bugs.

Comment: Also it is possible for a function to be side-effect free but still not pure, I believe.

Comment: But will compilers detect pure functions and optimize it away in that case?

Comment: @heishe What is a pure function and how do you detect it? Yes compilers will do optimizations, mostly through function inlining that can lead to a simplification of complex expressions.

Comment: @heishe i'm sure there are a subset of compilers which have an inherent notion of pure functions which will do this.  It's certainly not a feature of most main stream compilers though.

Answer (score 1):

Since your premise a flawed, no, they won't.

`(a()&&b()&&c()) || (a()&&b()&&!c())` definitely can't be rewritten as `(a()&&b())`

C (and C++) isn't a functional programming language (like Haskell).

Answer (score 1):

But the problem is that it  *can't* be refactored in that way, generally speaking!

If any of the functions have side effects that change the result of `c()` then the second call would possibly return a different result from the first one.

Not only that, but due to short-circuit execution things could be muddied even further.

Answer (score 1):

Very often in C the return value of a function gives whether the function was executed successfully of not.  For example calling a graphics routine, converting a file.  Think how often you use pointers to change something external to the function.  Or call another function that outputs something.  As someone said this isn't functional programming.

If the compiler is able to determine that foo() changes and does nothing then it may by all means simplify it but I would NOT count on it.

Here is a very simple example

```
bool foo()
{
    std::cout << "this needs to be printed each time foo() is called, even though its called in a logical expression\n";
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if ((foo() && !(foo()) || foo() && !(foo())))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Edit any boolean algebra of variables should be simplified.